# Aurelia bundling relative vs. absolute paths

Tags: aurelia

I'm working on an Aurelia project with a few bundles. Our aurelia.json file has a "bundles" section that includes this:

```
    "bundles": [
        {
            "name": "public-bundle.js",
            "source": {
                "include": [
                    "[**/*.js]",
                    "[**/*.html]"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                    "**/foo/**/*",
                    "**/bar/**/*"
                ]
            }
        },
        [...]
```

On my machine "public-bundle.js" was coming out as an empty file, while on my co-workers it was working properly.

After a lot of investigation I found the problem. My files are kept in a folder whose path includes the substring \foo\ (e.g. c:\users\foo\project-base-folder). Turns out the bundler is applying that "exclude" glob pattern to the *absolute* path of all files, so it's picking up on the \foo\ in my full file path and excluding *everything*.

I'd like to have the bundler evaluate the *relative* path of the project contents, not the absolute path, so that it's guaranteed to apply those rules consistently in any environment. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: does `exclude: `./**/foo/**/*` change something?

Comment: @FabioLuz No, that had the effect of excluding nothing, so all files went into public-bundle and the foo and bar bundles are empty. It looks like it should be right though! `exclude: "./foo/**/*"` failed in the same way.

Comment: @FabioLuz Also failed on `exclude: "./full-path-to/foo/**/*"` where full-path is based at the project root.